# ¿Como mover dibujos en una cuadricula?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, opengl

necesito orientación con el siguiente problema. 
Tengo una serie de figuras dibujadas con OpenGl, tengo implementado ya un método para mover las figuras y funciona bien, ademas tengo otro método que dibuja una rejilla según unos parámetros que le pasa el usuario. Es caso es que necesito ajustar el movimiento a la cuadricula y obligar a que el movimiento de los objetos siempre se ajuste a la cuadricula. Algo así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La cuadricula siempre se ajusta a unos ejes de coordenadas que el usuario puede mover para ajustar el dibujo a la pantalla. ¿Alguna idea de como lograr esto?

Comment: Tu pregunta es poco clara. Considera mirar [ask].. como lograr que cosa? que intentaste hasta ahora?

Comment: Redondea las coordenadas reales a la coordenada de cuadrícula más cercana o a la baja.